# Using DynamoDB -> Resource not found

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In order to set up a system on `AWS` where one can create and use user accounts from an iOS app, I recently followed [this tutorial](https://video.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search?fr=yhs-Lkry-SF01&hsimp=yhs-SF01&hspart=Lkry&p=How%20to%20sign%20up%20on%20Cognito%20with%20Swift%3F&guccounter=2#id=34&vid=5aec60106873a289acfa42bb5e7b16d8) which uses `AWSMobileClient`, `AWSAuthCore` and `AWSAuthUI`.

I got up something working where I can create accounts and log in and out.

Now I would like to make use of `DynamoDB` to allow the user to store something. For that, I have tried to integrate `DynamoDB` code that I have working in another app. But obviously the two apps environment are not quite the same, so it does not work as I would like it to.

Here is the code for the DynamoDB data that I want to handle:

```
import Foundation
import AWSDynamoDB

@objcMembers
class DynamoDBData: AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling {

    var _message,_timeStamp,_user: String?

    class func dynamoDBTableName() -> String {
        return "DynamoDBData"
    }

    class func hashKeyAttribute() -> String {
        return "_timeStamp"
    }

    class func rangeKeyAttribute() -> String {
        return "_user"
    }

    override class func jsonKeyPathsByPropertyKey() -> [AnyHashable: Any] {
        return [
            "_message" : "message",
            "_timeStamp" : "timeStamp",
            "_user" : "user"
        ]
    }
}
```

And here is the code for where I try to save something to the DB and fail:

```
@objc func handleTap() {
    print(#function)
    let dynamoDbObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.default()

    // Create data object using the data model:
    let dataBlock = DynamoDBData()
    dataBlock?._message = "message-TEST"
    dataBlock?._timeStamp = "timeStamp-TEST"
    dataBlock?._user = "user-TEST"

    // Save the new item:
    dynamoDbObjectMapper.save(dataBlock!, completionHandler: {
        (error: Error?) -> Void in

        if let error = error {
            print("Amazon DynamoDB Save Error: \(error)")
            return
        }
        print("An item was saved.")
    })
}
```

Finally, this is the message I get showing a problem when trying to save data:

```
Amazon DynamoDB Save Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSDynamoDBErrorDomain Code=19 "(null)"
 UserInfo={__type=com.amazonaws.dynamodb.v20120810#ResourceNotFoundException, 
 message=Requested resource not found}
```

Since I have created a table DynamoDBData on the AWS console, I do not really understand why it says "Requested resource not found", but I guess I must have done something wrong at some point.

In case this can be useful, here is what appears in the AWS console for the table DynamoDBData:

```
Table name  DynamoDBData
Primary partition key   _timeStamp (String)
Primary sort key    _user (String)
Point-in-time recovery  DISABLED Enable
Encryption Type DEFAULT Manage Encryption
KMS Master Key ARN  Not Applicable
Time to live attribute  DISABLED Manage TTL
Table status    Active
Creation date   May 15, 2019 at 10:13:43 AM UTC+9
UTC: May 15, 2019 at 1:13:43 AM UTC
Local: May 15, 2019 at 10:13:43 AM UTC+9
Region (N. Virginia): May 14, 2019 at 8:13:43 PM UTC-5
Read/write capacity mode    Provisioned
Last change to on-demand mode   -
Provisioned read capacity units 5 (Auto Scaling Disabled)
Provisioned write capacity units    5 (Auto Scaling Disabled)
Last decrease time  -
Last increase time  -Storage size (in bytes)    0 bytes
Item count  0 Manage live count
Region  US East (N. Virginia)
Amazon Resource Name (ARN)  arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:123456789012:table/DynamoDBData
```

Some guidance (even partial) on how to solve this issue would be very helpful.

Comment: Alternatively, instead of calling DynamoDB directly from your app, it looks like what you want to achieve can be done with AWS Amplify framework https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/ios/start

You could use Amplify CLI to provision a graphQL service managed by AppSync which persists/queries against your DynamoDB. Use AWSMobileClient to authenticate your users and requests to your AppSync service to interact with dynamoDB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing to double check: is the table's region the same region you're trying to access it in?

I noticed from a comment in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56123009/using-dynamodb-within-ios-after-authentication/56128084) that the code was attempting to reach arn:aws:dynamodb:`ap-northeast-1` but the above shows the table is actually in `us-east-1`.

Comment: Yes. You're right (once more). When I create a table in the ap-northeast-1, the issue disappears. Nevertheless I get yet another problem (maybe some kind of data mismatch) with this message: Amazon DynamoDB Save Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException, message=The provided key element does not match the schema}

Comment: Finally I am able to save an item. I had to use timeStamp and user instead of _timeStamp and _user, when creating the table in AWS console.